Bark/Coqui voice cloning on CPU restarts computer
I am using CoquiTTS and Bark to create a text to speech like below. Each time I run this program on my CPU based machine, the CPU spikes to 100% a few times and eventually after a few minutes the machine restarts. How can I run this program locally?
from TTS.tts.configs.bark_config import BarkConfig
from TTS.tts.models.bark import Bark
import scipy

config = BarkConfig()
model = Bark.init_from_config(config)
model.load_checkpoint(config, checkpoint_dir="bark/", eval=True)

text = "Hope you found this video useful. How goes it?"

output_dict = model.synthesize(text, config, speaker_id="speaker", voice_dirs="bark_voices/")

